# Fourier series period?

Tags: series, fourier

This might seem basic to most of you but I'd like some help with a DT FS question if possible.

From what I understand, the period of a DT signal N is defined as the value such that x[n] = x[n + N].

I have the solution to question here that states the period is N. Should the period not be (N + 1)?

Similarly, in my summation to find the FS coefficients, should I not sum from (0 to N), rather than (0 to N-1)?

Thank you.

[image: Depiction of Question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The period is indeed \$N\$: the sample at index \$n=N\$ corresponds to the sample at \$n=0\$. So if you continued the sequence to the left (i.e. towards negative indices), there would be three samples with value \$1\$.

For finding the coefficients you need to sum over one period, i.e. you have to sum from \$0\$ to \$N-1\$ (which are \$N\$ values). You might as well some from some index \$n_0\$ to \$n_0+N-1\$ (which again are exactly \$N\$ values).

Comment: Ok, say I had a signal that went |..| and was then repeated periodically. This signal has a period of 4 because there are 4 indexes in one period. In my OP, there are (N + 1) indexes. Hence, should the period not be (N + 1) by the same logic?

Comment: @Tim: Who told you that there are N+1 indices in the period? According to what you're given, the period is N, and therefore the sample at index N is already the first sample of the next period. The period is the samples from index 0 up to and including index N-1. You can't see this from the figure, it's just part of the problem you're given. If they tell you that N is the period you just have to believe it, unless you can conclude from the figure that this is wrong, but that's not the case here.